# Karnaugh map - assign variables to the inputs?

Tags: logic

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ITPF7qU.png]

I drew the map on the right, but what I drew doesn't work for what the question is asking me. I think I did something very wrong, and I don't really understand what this question is asking me. Am i suppose to re arrange the binary inputs somehow?

Comment: Could you please label the inputs w,x,y,z in the diagram ?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. Not only is it lazy, it also makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and maths (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $w,x,y,z$ are inputs to the circuit given. What we need is $$\sum_{w,x,y,z}(2,3,8,9)$$

Put this in a Karnaugh Map and you will get the simplified equation as $w^\prime x^\prime y + wx^\prime y^\prime$. Now, let $a,b,c,d$ be the inputs to the circuit that you have given. Output of first **OR gate** will be $a+b$. Let it be called $f$. Output of second **OR gate** will be $c+d$. Let it be called $s$. Output of the **XOR gate** is $fs^\prime+sf^\prime$. Substitue the values of $f$ and $s$ in the equation and use the equality $(\alpha+\beta)^\prime=\alpha^\prime \beta^\prime$The output will be $$a^\prime b^\prime\cdot(c+d)+c^\prime d^\prime\cdot(a+b)$$.

Compare this with the equation that we require and we find that $$a=w$$$$b=x$$$$c=x$$$$d=y$$
These are the order in which inputs should be given.

Karnaugh Map that you have drawn is correct assuming that $w,x,y,z$ are inputs to the circuit.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. The karnaugh map represents the OR-XOR circuit (fig.1) where the input from top to bottom is w,x,y,z. so when w=1,x=0,y=0,z=0 (the top right cell in the map) then F=1. isnt that how the Karnaugh map works? I am unsure on how you get that simplified equation, and I dont know how you get that output equation

Comment: also, isnt the simplified equation wx'y'+yw'x' ? http://i.imgur.com/AZM3HWp.png

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. I edited the answer

Comment: @user14864 Yeah, logically that's how Karnaugh Map is to be filled. See some standard logic design book to know how to simplify the Karnaugh Map

Comment: Ok now, how did you find the equation a'b'⋅(c+d)+c'd'⋅(a+b) ?

Comment: See the answer now